# Inserting multiple checkboxsed into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create something like quiz in php and mysql. It's just for fun, but still, I have a problem with submitting `radio` inputs. Example of HTML:

```
    <input type="radio" name="news[]" value="0"><label>Nie</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="news[]" value="1"><label>Tak</label>
```

and my SQL is as follows:

```
$answer1 = $_POST['news'];
$answer2 = $_POST['politics];

mysql_query('INSERT INTO quiz (id, answer1, answer2...) VALUES (null, $answer1, $answer2...);
```

It alsways inserts `0`, no matter what will I check. I know I cal solve this by using `foreach`, but this will - I think - create multiple `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Welcome to the world of SQL Injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I tried using `mysql_real_escape_string`, but it returns that `$answer1` is an array.

Comment: ofcourse you use input array that's why it returns an array()

Comment: why are you using news[] if working with radio type? If you would to track multiple answers, should use checkbox's type instead of radio, and name those like answer1, answer2 etc instead of an array pass if you dont like the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try use a for loop:

```
   $n = count($_POST['news']);
   for($x = 0; $x < $nl $x++){
       mysql_query('INSERT INTO quiz (id, answer1, answer2) VALUES (null, $answer1[$x], $answer2[$x]);
   }
```

Comment: Woudn't this create multiple `INSERT` statements?

Comment: It would, which is what you're asking for unless your table schema has a column for each choice (which would be a bad idea).

Comment: @TomekBuszewski If you want to insert it in a single statement then you shouldn't use input arrays